# Standard 404 Error NOT displaying.

Tags: php, url, routes, http-status-code-404

I have a website (URL: http://www.fromthepitch.com). There seems to be a problem with it issuing error codes. For some reason instead of 404 error page it displays the home page. http://www.fromthepitch.com/asdsad is meant to show a 404 page but instead displays the home page. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Comment: What does your `.htaccess` look like?

Comment: Are you using some hosting provider out there? Perhaps they have redirection rules (.htaccess files, mod_rewrite config) that send requests back to home site.

Comment: using vidahost on a shared server. The other website I have on there works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a shared hosting account. The domain for fromthepitch.com was in a sub folder of this domain for retailerwork.com which is the main domain on the hosting account. fromthepitch.com's htaccess was being overwritten by retailerwork.com's htaccess. Vidahost my hosting company helped me solve this in a matter of moments on their support line. I hade to turn the RewriteEngine off before inserting the line of code to point to a custom 404 page. I just did not have the knowledge to understand. Maybe if i put more information it would have been clear. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

in your .htaccess set this line

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.html
```

and you customise your error_404.html page

Comment: Won't help if there's any mod_rewrite stuff taking place.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. still redirected to the home page :-/

Comment: @user1712718 Let me ask what the others already did, since you seem to not take notice. **What does the `.htaccess` file contain?**

Comment: original i had an htaccess file. i tried to make the urls seo friendly. but that didnt work so i took it off. then i noticed it wasnt displayin 404s. i tried chokrijobs errordocument thing but that did not work. currently no htaccess on site.